# Java Concurrency: how to get the worker thread's response asynchronously

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am new to `java.util.concurrent` package. I'm trying to write some samples. 
Here is my some sample code snippet:

```
for (MyTask task : tasks) { 
Future<Boolean> result = task.getResult();
try {
    if (result.isCancelled()) {
        logger.info("processResults():  cancelled: "+ ((MyTask) task).getName());
    } else if (result.get() == false) {
        logger.info("processResults(): Failed : "+ ((MyTask) task).getName());
    } else {
        logger.info("processResults(): successful: "+ ((MyTask) task).getName());
        tasks.remove(task);
        continue; 
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warn("processResults(): Excepiton: " + e.getMessage());
} 
}
```

I have one question regarding the handling the Future object from worker thread. in my for loop the handling of tasks is in sequential manner; lets say, I need to process the return results from the worker thread, if my 2nd worker thread is completed before the first one, in my code there is no way to process the 2nd worker thread first.

Can anybody suggest the best way to handle current threds.

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform some work as soon as the task finishes you can do that in the same thread. i.e. change the task to do everything and have it return a value **after** everything is done.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey, Lets say, each of my thread return some results, I need to cumulate all the results from each worker thread. How can i do this?

Comment: Read my answer for how to do it.

Comment: You can have each thread accumulate the results. However, if you want simplicity, use the Future's as it cannot finish until the last task is finished.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case for using the producer-consumer pattern: Have the tasks (producers) put their results on a queue and have the "next step" code (consumers) take the results from the queue and continue working.

An ArrayBlockingQueue would be a good choice. A second set of worker threads calls `take()` on the queue blocks until something is available (when your 1st step threads calls `put()` on the queue).

Answer (score 1):

The problem sounds tailor made for a [java.util.concurrent.CompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html)

The purpose of a CompletionService is to decouple the production of tasks from consumption of the results of those tasks.

The result consumer can be in the same thread as the task producer, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for [Java NIO (Non-blocking IO)](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html).
[This article](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html) is from Java 1.4 but still will give you a good understanding of how to setup NIO. Since then NIO have evolved a lot and you may need to look up the API for [Java 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) or [Java 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) to find out whats new.